# orthogonal projection with numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a list of 3D-points for which I calculate a plane by numpy.linalg.lstsq - method. But Now I want to do a orthogonal projection for each point into this plane, but I can't find my mistake:

```
from numpy.linalg import lstsq

def VecProduct(vek1, vek2):
    return (vek1[0]*vek2[0] + vek1[1]*vek2[1] + vek1[2]*vek2[2])

def CalcPlane(x, y, z):
    # x, y and z are given in lists
    n = len(x)
    sum_x = sum_y = sum_z = sum_xx = sum_yy = sum_xy = sum_xz = sum_yz = 0
    for i in range(n):
        sum_x += x[i] 
        sum_y += y[i]
        sum_z += z[i]
        sum_xx += x[i]*x[i]
        sum_yy += y[i]*y[i]
        sum_xy += x[i]*y[i]
        sum_xz += x[i]*z[i]
        sum_yz += y[i]*z[i]

    M = ([sum_xx, sum_xy, sum_x], [sum_xy, sum_yy, sum_y], [sum_x, sum_y, n])
    b = (sum_xz, sum_yz, sum_z)

    a,b,c = lstsq(M, b)[0]

    '''
    z = a*x + b*y + c
    a*x = z - b*y - c
    x = -(b/a)*y + (1/a)*z - c/a 
    '''

    r0 = [-c/a, 
          0, 
          0]

    u = [-b/a,
         1,
         0]

    v = [1/a,
         0,
         1]

    xn = []
    yn = []
    zn = []

    # orthogonalize u and v with Gram-Schmidt to get u and w

    uu = VecProduct(u, u)
    vu = VecProduct(v, u)
    fak0 = vu/uu
    erg0 = [val*fak0 for val in u]
    w = [v[0]-erg0[0], 
        v[1]-erg0[1], 
        v[2]-erg0[2]]
    ww = VecProduct(w, w)

    # P_new = ((x*u)/(u*u))*u + ((x*w)/(w*w))*w
    for i in range(len(x)):
        xu = VecProduct([x[i], y[i], z[i]], u)
        xw = VecProduct([x[i], y[i], z[i]], w)
        fak1 = xu/uu
        fak2 = xw/ww
        erg1 = [val*fak1 for val in u]
        erg2 = [val*fak2 for val in w]
        erg = [erg1[0]+erg2[0], erg1[1]+erg2[1], erg1[2]+erg2[2]]
        erg[0] += r0[0] 
        xn.append(erg[0])
        yn.append(erg[1])
        zn.append(erg[2])

    return (xn,yn,zn)
```

This returns me a list of points which are all in a plane, but when I display them, they are not at the positions they should be.
I believe there is already a certain built-in method to solve this problem, but I couldn't find any =(

Comment: I found my mistake: I made a wrong assumption: My calculation for P_new is wrong. This is correct: P_new = r0 + (((x-r0)*u)/(u*u))*u + (((x-r0)*w)/(w*w))*w

Comment: Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization algorithm [here](https://python-advanced.quantecon.org/orth_proj.html)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are doing a very poor use of `np.lstsq`, since you are feeding it a precomputed 3x3 matrix, instead of letting it do the job. I would do it like this:

```
import numpy as np

def calc_plane(x, y, z):
    a = np.column_stack((x, y, np.ones_like(x)))
    return np.linalg.lstsq(a, z)[0]

>>> x = np.random.rand(1000)
>>> y = np.random.rand(1000)
>>> z = 4*x + 5*y + 7 + np.random.rand(1000)*.1
>>> calc_plane(x, y, z)
array([ 3.99795126,  5.00233364,  7.05007326])
```

It is actually more convenient to use a formula for your plane that doesn't depend on the coefficient of `z` not being zero, i.e. use `a*x + b*y + c*z = 1`. You can similarly compute `a`, `b` and `c` doing:

```
def calc_plane_bis(x, y, z):
    a = np.column_stack((x, y, z))
    return np.linalg.lstsq(a, np.ones_like(x))[0]
>>> calc_plane_bis(x, y, z)
array([-0.56732299, -0.70949543,  0.14185393])
```

To project points onto a plane, using my alternative equation, the vector `(a, b, c)` is perpendicular to the plane. It is easy to check that the point `(a, b, c) / (a**2+b**2+c**2)` is on the plane, so projection can be done by referencing all points to that point on the plane, projecting the points onto the normal vector, subtract that projection from the points, then referencing them back to the origin. You could do that as follows:

```
def project_points(x, y, z, a, b, c):
    """
    Projects the points with coordinates x, y, z onto the plane
    defined by a*x + b*y + c*z = 1
    """
    vector_norm = a*a + b*b + c*c
    normal_vector = np.array([a, b, c]) / np.sqrt(vector_norm)
    point_in_plane = np.array([a, b, c]) / vector_norm

    points = np.column_stack((x, y, z))
    points_from_point_in_plane = points - point_in_plane
    proj_onto_normal_vector = np.dot(points_from_point_in_plane,
                                     normal_vector)
    proj_onto_plane = (points_from_point_in_plane -
                       proj_onto_normal_vector[:, None]*normal_vector)

    return point_in_plane + proj_onto_plane
```

So now you can do something like:

```
>>> project_points(x, y, z, *calc_plane_bis(x, y, z))
array([[  0.13138012,   0.76009389,  11.37555123],
       [  0.71096929,   0.68711773,  13.32843506],
       [  0.14889398,   0.74404116,  11.36534936],
       ..., 
       [  0.85975642,   0.4827624 ,  12.90197969],
       [  0.48364383,   0.2963717 ,  10.46636903],
       [  0.81596472,   0.45273681,  12.57679188]])
```

Comment: @Munchkin I just realized that the code above is assuming that your plane does not go through the origin, i.e. it cannot be used to project onto a plane with equation `a*x + b*y + c*z = 0`. Not sure how to easily work around it without too many complications, but be aware of this important caveat.

Comment: oh thank you, yesterday i only tested it with a plane which goes through origin, but you're right: it's not correct for planes outside the origin. i did the following:

Comment: calculate the arithmetic mean of all x,y,z-values; move all points by this value (so that the center of this scatter-plot goes through origin) and then startet your code. after that I moved all points 'backwards'. Now I have a plane which **looks** ok, but it is at a wrong place in my coordinate system. I **think** it is just at the correct x-position, but not at the correct y- and z-position in the co-system. Has it something to do with that line: `return np.linalg.lstsq(a, np.ones_like(x))[0]` ?

Comment: The standard way of allowing planes through the origin is to use homogeneous coordinates (e.g. add a 4th dimension which is always 1).

Answer (score 8):

You can simply do everything in matrices is one option.

If you add your points as row vectors to a matrix `X`, and `y` is a vector, then the parameters vector `beta` for the least squares solution are:

```
import numpy as np

beta = np.linalg.inv(X.T.dot(X)).dot(X.T.dot(y))
```

but there's an easier way, if we want to do projections: QR decomposition gives us an orthonormal projection matrix, as `Q.T`, and `Q` is itself the matrix of orthonormal basis vectors.  So, we can first form `QR`, then get `beta`, then use `Q.T` to project the points.

QR:

```
Q, R = np.linalg.qr(X)
```

beta:

```
# use R to solve for beta
# R is upper triangular, so can use triangular solver:
beta = scipy.solve_triangular(R, Q.T.dot(y))
```

So now we have `beta`, and we can project the points using `Q.T` very simply:

```
X_proj = Q.T.dot(X)
```

Thats it!

If you want more information and graphical piccies and stuff, I made a whole bunch of notes, whilst doing something similar, at: https://github.com/hughperkins/selfstudy-IBP/blob/9dedfbb93f4320ac1bfef60db089ae0dba5e79f6/test_bases.ipynb

(Edit: note that if you want to add a bias term, so the best-fit doesnt have to pass through the origin, you can simply add an additional column, with all-1s, to `X`, which acts as the bias term/feature)

Comment: I like the QR method of solving for beta. However, I can't get the X_proj to work. Q is an Nx3 matrix (at least with the default mode='reduced'), so `Q.T.dot(X)` is a 3x3 matrix. Definitely not the projection we wanted.

Comment: QR is right, but if you only need projection, you don't need to calculate beta. The projection simply equals to Q @ Q.T @ y

Comment: plus you need make sure X has full rank and qr is in 'reduced' mode.

Answer (score 0):

This web [page](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/vector-projection-using-python/) has a pretty great code base.  It implements the [theory](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=MathApps/ProjectionOfVectorOntoPlane) expounded by Maple in `numpy` quite well, as follows:

```
# import numpy to perform operations on vector 
import numpy as np 
  
# vector u  
u = np.array([2, 5, 8])        
  
# vector n: n is orthogonal vector to Plane P 
n = np.array([1, 1, 7])        
   
# Task: Project vector u on Plane P 
  
# finding norm of the vector n  
n_norm = np.sqrt(sum(n**2))     
   
# Apply the formula as mentioned above 
# for projecting a vector onto the orthogonal vector n 
# find dot product using np.dot() 
proj_of_u_on_n = (np.dot(u, n)/n_norm**2)*n 
  
# subtract proj_of_u_on_n from u:  
# this is the projection of u on Plane P 
print("Projection of Vector u on Plane P is: ", u - proj_of_u_on_n)
```

Comment: cannot apply to 2D-matrix

Comment: @JeeyCi do you think my answer states that the code is for projecting from a plane (2-D) onto a line (1-D)?

Comment: the question of the topic was about 3D-points projection onto the plane, as I see... line can be present in [Cartesian coordinate system](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system)  as well , as is more than 1D. and even larger amount of axis... just tested your code