# Optimized projection of a matrix orthogonaly to a vector with Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, qr-decomposition

I need to make all other columns of a matrix `A` orthogonal to one of its column `j`.

I use the following algorithm :

```
# Orthogonalize with selected column
for i in remaining_cols:
    A[:,i] = A[:,i] - A[:,j] * np.dot(A[:,i], A[:,j]) / np.sum(A[:,j]**2)
```

The idea comes from the [QR decomposition with the Gram-Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition#Using_the_Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process).

But this code is not optimized and unstable because of the Gram-Schmidt process.

Does Numpy provide any method to compute the orthogonal projection of those vectors ?

---

### With Householder Matrix

I heard that the Householder Reflectors are used in `numpy.linalg.qr`. This would allow me to compute an orthogonal matrix `Q` so that

```
Q * A[:,j] = [0 ... 0 1 0 ... 0]
                      |
                 j_th coordinate
```

I would only have to ignore the line `j` and multiply back with `Q.T`.

Is there a method to obtain the Householder Matrix with Numpy ? I mean without coding the algorithm by hand.

Comment: Have read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836880/orthogonal-projection-with-numpy)?

Comment: @Ben.T I did come across it, but I thought it was unrelated. Indeed I don't deal with Least Square problem, but maybe there is a connection ?

Comment: @Ben.T to my knowledge, LS problem enables to find an hyperplane closest to your data in terms of the euclidean distance. In my case, I have a specific projection hyperplane, the one that has the `A[:,j]`as normal vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, here could be a vectorized way:

```
np.random.seed(10)
B = np.random.rand(3,3)

col = 0
remaining_cols = [1,2]

#your method
A = B.copy()
for i in remaining_cols:
    A[:,i] = A[:,i] - A[:,col] * np.dot(A[:,i], A[:,col]) / np.sum(A[:,col]**2)
print (A)
[[ 0.77132064 -0.32778252  0.18786796]
 [ 0.74880388  0.16014712 -0.2079702 ]
 [ 0.19806286  0.67103261  0.05464156]]

# vectorize method
A = B.copy()
A[:,remaining_cols] -= (A[:,col][:,None] * np.sum(A[:,remaining_cols]* A[:,col][:,None], axis=0)
                                              / np.sum(A[:,col]**2))

print (A) #same result
[[ 0.77132064 -0.32778252  0.18786796]
 [ 0.74880388  0.16014712 -0.2079702 ]
 [ 0.19806286  0.67103261  0.05464156]]
```

Comment: Works pretty nicely thanks ! I haven't accepted to see if there can be other propositions, especially using some Numpy optimized method.

Comment: @matthiasbe good to know it works and no pb, I assume there is an implemented method, but broadcasting is usually good regarding performance as far I know :)