# How to write this orthogonal projection formula in python?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, pca, orthogonal

projection of a vector    onto a 1-dimensional subspace    with basis vector

()=‖‖2

And for the general projection onto an M-dimensional subspace    with basis vectors

()=()−1

where

=[1,...,]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [orthogonal projection with numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836880/orthogonal-projection-with-numpy)

Answer (score 0):

Sure:

```
import numpy as np
v = np.array([1, 2, 3])
# Has to be a unit vector!
v = v/np.linalg.norm(v)

# Projection matrix unto the v direction
P = np.outer(v, v)

# Projection matrix unto the plane with a normal of v
T = np.eye(len(v)) - P
```